# IIF condition in Stimulsoft Reporting Tool

Tags: reporting-services, stimulsoft

Having problems with if condition in Stimulsoft Reporting tool.

Context: Building a report in Stimulsoft Reporting tool. The report will use If conditions to show progress of assets.

Problem: When writing the iif condition i encounter error

"Cannot be assigned to read only error"

My clause: 
{IIF(Test.Test=1),"l",""}

Whereas the same Condition in SSRS is working 
=IIF((Fields!Test.Value) = 1, "l","")

Any suggestions.

Comment: Solution :  {IIF(Test.Test =="1","l","")}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stimulsoft is treating `=` as assignment, not Boolean comparison. Use `==`:

```
{IIF(Test.Test =="1","l","")}
```

Comment: I tried that getting this error.

 The error of compilation
The error of compilation is found in the 'Text' property of the 'Table1_Cell39' component:
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

 and 

The error of compilation
The error of compilation is found in the 'Text' property of the 'Table1_Cell39' component:
No overload for method 'ToString' takes 5 arguments

Comment: Then you need to compare Test to a string `"1"` and not an int `1`. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I used conditions in StimulSoft like this:

`{Test.Test=="1"?"1":""}`